# Minimal page size for 2 tikzpictures

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, standalone, axis

I am trying to prepare a graph for a colleague to use. I have created the graph but wanted to crop the white space surrounding it.

I have tried to use the `standalone` document class but this results in the `tikzpicture`s appearing side by side, rather than on top of each other.

Is there a better way to crop this PDF?

Example:

```
\documentclass[border=2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[svgnames,dvipsnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepackage{geometry}
\pgfplotsset{ every non boxed x axis/.append style={x axis line style=-} }
\pgfplotsset{ every non boxed y axis/.append style={y axis line style=-} }
\usepackage[eulergreek]{sansmath}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\pgfplotsset
{
  tick label style = {font=\sansmath\sffamily},
  every axis label = {font=\sansmath\sffamily},
tick style={black},
}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left]
\pgfplotsset{set layers}
\begin{axis}[
axis on top=true,
width=14cm,
height=8cm,
ylabel=\textbf{A},
title={Title},
xlabel=\textbf{B},
xmin = -0.2, xmax = 10,
xtick={0,1,...,10},
minor x tick num=4,
minor y tick num=4,
ymin = 0, ymax = 350,
ytick={0,25,...,350},
axis y line=left,
axis x line=bottom,
major tick style = {semithick, black},
legend style={draw=none, font=\small},
]
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[
axis on top=true,
width=14cm,
height=8cm,
ylabel=\textbf{C},
xmin = -0.2, xmax = 10,
xtick={0,1,...,10},
minor x tick num=4,
minor y tick num=4,
ymin = 25, ymax = 135,
ytick={35,45,...,135},
axis y discontinuity=crunch,
major tick style = {semithick, black},
legend style={draw=none},
axis y line=right,
axis x line=none,
]
\end{axis}


\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left]
\begin{axis}
[
width=14cm,
domain=-0.2:10,
axis x line=bottom, 
axis y line=none,
xlabel=\textbf{Fraction},
ymin = 0, ymax = 1,
tick label style={font=\tiny},
xtick={-0.002267,0.498043,0.997959,1.102242,1.310256,2.060156,2.810043,3.561611,4.311513,5.061414,5.811329,6.561231,7.312812,7.959396,10},
xticklabel=\empty,
major tick style = {semithick, black},
axis line style=black,thick,
extra x ticks={0.247888,0.748001,1.0501005,1.206249,1.685206,2.4350995,3.185827,3.936562,4.6864635,5.4363715,6.18628,6.9370215,7.636104,8.979698},
extra x tick labels={2B,3B,4B,5B,6B,7B,8B,9B,10B,11B,12B,13B,14B,Waste},
extra x tick style={major tick length=0pt}
]
\addplot [color=black]{0};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you like to obtain something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}  % <---
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[svgnames,dvipsnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.16,
   tick label style = {font=\sansmath\sffamily},
   every axis label = {font=\sansmath\sffamily},
         tick style = black,
every non boxed x axis/.append style={x axis line style=-},
every non boxed y axis/.append style={y axis line style=-},
            }
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns, positioning}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[eulergreek]{sansmath}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}   % <---
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}         % <---
\setlength\PreviewBorder{0pt}            % <---

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}%[trim axis left]
\pgfplotsset{set layers}
\begin{axis}[
axis on top=true,
width=14cm,
height=8cm,
ylabel=\textbf{A},
title={Title},
xlabel=\textbf{B},
xmin = -0.2, xmax = 10,
xtick={0,1,...,10},
minor x tick num=4,
minor y tick num=4,
ymin = 0, ymax = 350,
ytick={0,25,...,350},
axis y line=left,
axis x line=bottom,
major tick style = {semithick, black},
legend style={draw=none, font=\small},
]
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[
axis on top=true,
width=14cm,
height=8cm,
ylabel=\textbf{C},
xmin = -0.2, xmax = 10,
xtick={0,1,...,10},
minor x tick num=4,
minor y tick num=4,
ymin = 25, ymax = 135,
ytick={35,45,...,135},
axis y discontinuity=crunch,
major tick style = {semithick, black},
legend style={draw=none},
axis y line=right,
axis x line=none,
]
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}
[
axis x line shift=0.13,  % <--- shift of x axis
width=14cm,
domain=-0.2:10,
axis x line=bottom,
axis y line=none,
xlabel=\textbf{Fraction},
ymin = 0, ymax = 1,
tick label style={font=\tiny},
xtick={-0.002267,0.498043,0.997959,1.102242,1.310256,2.060156,2.810043,3.561611,4.311513,5.061414,5.811329,6.561231,7.312812,7.959396,10},
xticklabel=\empty,
major tick style = {semithick, black},
axis line style=black,thick,
extra x ticks={0.247888,0.748001,1.0501005,1.206249,1.685206,2.4350995,3.185827,3.936562,4.6864635,5.4363715,6.18628,6.9370215,7.636104,8.979698},
extra x tick labels={2B,3B,4B,5B,6B,7B,8B,9B,10B,11B,12B,13B,14B,Waste},
extra x tick style={major tick length=0pt}
]
\addplot [color=black]{0};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to TeX-SE! You could just add the second axis in the same `tikzpicture` and shift it wherever you want it to be.

```
\documentclass[border=2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[svgnames,dvipsnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
%\usepackage{geometry}
\pgfplotsset{ every non boxed x axis/.append style={x axis line style=-} }
\pgfplotsset{ every non boxed y axis/.append style={y axis line style=-} }
\usepackage[eulergreek]{sansmath}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\pgfplotsset{ tick label style = {font=\sansmath\sffamily},
  every axis label = {font=\sansmath\sffamily},
tick style={black},
}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\pgfplotsset{set layers}
\begin{axis}[trim axis left,
axis on top=true,
width=14cm,
height=8cm,
ylabel=\textbf{A},
title={Title},
xlabel=\textbf{B},
xmin = -0.2, xmax = 10,
xtick={0,1,...,10},
minor x tick num=4,
minor y tick num=4,
ymin = 0, ymax = 350,
ytick={0,25,...,350},
axis y line=left,
axis x line=bottom,
major tick style = {semithick, black},
legend style={draw=none, font=\small},
]
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[
axis on top=true,
width=14cm,
height=8cm,
ylabel=\textbf{C},
xmin = -0.2, xmax = 10,
xtick={0,1,...,10},
minor x tick num=4,
minor y tick num=4,
ymin = 25, ymax = 135,
ytick={35,45,...,135},
axis y discontinuity=crunch,
major tick style = {semithick, black},
legend style={draw=none},
axis y line=right,
axis x line=none,
]
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[at={(0,-8cm)},trim axis left]
[
width=14cm,
domain=-0.2:10,
axis x line=bottom, 
axis y line=none,
xlabel=\textbf{Fraction},
ymin = 0, ymax = 1,
tick label style={font=\tiny},
xtick={-0.002267,0.498043,0.997959,1.102242,1.310256,2.060156,2.810043,3.561611,4.311513,5.061414,5.811329,6.561231,7.312812,7.959396,10},
xticklabel=\empty,
major tick style = {semithick, black},
axis line style=black,thick,
extra x ticks={0.247888,0.748001,1.0501005,1.206249,1.685206,2.4350995,3.185827,3.936562,4.6864635,5.4363715,6.18628,6.9370215,7.636104,8.979698},
extra x tick labels={2B,3B,4B,5B,6B,7B,8B,9B,10B,11B,12B,13B,14B,Waste},
extra x tick style={major tick length=0pt}
]
\addplot [color=black]{0};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To see the difference, your example output using background colors:

[image]

If your TeX-Editor supports `magic comments`, you can crop your pdf using, for instance, `pdfcrop.exe`, which should be included in your `Latex` distribution. For `TeXstudio`, `Windows`, `pdflatex` and `TeXlive`, the same example output after `pdfcrop.exe`:

```
% !TeX TXS-program:pdflatex = "C:\texlive2019\bin\win32\pdflatex.exe" -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex | "C:\texlive2019\bin\win32\pdfcrop.exe" %.pdf %.pdf
```

[image]

Therefore, you have to place this command at the beginning of your file:

```
            % !TeX TXS-program:pdflatex = "C:\texlive2019\bin\win32\pdflatex.exe" -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex |  "C:\texlive2019\bin\win32\pdfcrop.exe" %.pdf %.pdf

            \documentclass[border=2cm]{standalone}
            \usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
            \renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault} 
            \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
            \usepackage[svgnames,dvipsnames,x11names]{xcolor}
            \usepackage{pgfplots}
            \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
            \usepackage{geometry}
            \pgfplotsset{ every non boxed x axis/.append style={x axis line style=-} }
            \pgfplotsset{ every non boxed y axis/.append style={y axis line style=-} }
            \usepackage[eulergreek]{sansmath}
            \usetikzlibrary{patterns}
            \pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
            \pgfplotsset
            {
              tick label style = {font=\sansmath\sffamily},
              every axis label = {font=\sansmath\sffamily},
            tick style={black},
            }
            \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
            \pagestyle{empty}
            \begin{document}
            \colorbox{gray!20}{% added
            \begin{tikzpicture}%[trim axis left]
            \pgfplotsset{set layers}
            \begin{axis}[
            axis on top=true,
            width=14cm,
            height=8cm,
            ylabel=\textbf{A},
            title={Title},
            xlabel=\textbf{B},
            xmin = -0.2, xmax = 10,
            xtick={0,1,...,10},
            minor x tick num=4,
            minor y tick num=4,
            ymin = 0, ymax = 350,
            ytick={0,25,...,350},
            axis y line=left,
            axis x line=bottom,
            major tick style = {semithick, black},
            legend style={draw=none, font=\small},
            ]
            \end{axis}

            \begin{axis}[
            axis on top=true,
            width=14cm,
            height=8cm,
            ylabel=\textbf{C},
            xmin = -0.2, xmax = 10,
            xtick={0,1,...,10},
            minor x tick num=4,
            minor y tick num=4,
            ymin = 25, ymax = 135,
            ytick={35,45,...,135},
            axis y discontinuity=crunch,
            major tick style = {semithick, black},
            legend style={draw=none},
            axis y line=right,
            axis x line=none,
            ]
            \end{axis}


            \end{tikzpicture}

            \begin{tikzpicture}%[trim axis left]
            \begin{axis}
            [
            width=14cm,
            domain=-0.2:10,
            axis x line=bottom, 
            axis y line=none,
            xlabel=\textbf{Fraction},
            ymin = 0, ymax = 1,
            tick label style={font=\tiny},
            xtick={-0.002267,0.498043,0.997959,1.102242,1.310256,2.060156,2.810043,3.561611,4.311513,5.061414,5.811329,6.561231,7.312812,7.959396,10},
            xticklabel=\empty,
            major tick style = {semithick, black},
            axis line style=black,thick,
            extra x ticks={0.247888,0.748001,1.0501005,1.206249,1.685206,2.4350995,3.185827,3.936562,4.6864635,5.4363715,6.18628,6.9370215,7.636104,8.979698},
            extra x tick labels={2B,3B,4B,5B,6B,7B,8B,9B,10B,11B,12B,13B,14B,Waste},
            extra x tick style={major tick length=0pt}
            ]
            \addplot [color=black]{0};
            \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
            } % from \colorbox
            \end{document}
```

When compiling here will be a warning that the compilation command will be overridden. Please answer (a) `allow for this document`:

[image]

Please just press `ok` to the next warning to continue with the compilation (you do not need to change the commands configuration in `options` menu).

Afterwards `TeXstudio` place automatically a document-id `magic comment` at the top of the file (for example):

```
            % !TeX document-id = {b55a4920-174f-4c2e-be5a-b002ab325eb5}
```

Another possibility to crop is by using the command line or even with a windows `batch file`, see [Windows batch file for pdfcrop - GitHub](https://github.com/aminophen/bcpdfcrop).

If you want to place the second `x-axis` underneath the first `x-axis`, see [Zarko](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/18189/zarko)´s solution and if you want to place the tikzpictures on top of each other, see [marmot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/121799/marmot) ´s solution.

**Extra:** You can use `latexmk.exe -c` just to clean up auxiliary files, too:

```
            "C:\texlive2019\bin\win32\latexmk.exe" -c
```

That is:

```
  % !TeX TXS-program:pdflatex = "C:\texlive2019\bin\win32\pdflatex.exe" -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex | "C:\texlive2019\bin\win32\pdfcrop.exe" %.pdf %.pdf | "C:\texlive2019\bin\win32\latexmk.exe" -c
```